# Custom ActionMode in AlertDialog

Tags: java, android, android-dialogfragment, android-dialog, android-actionmode

I spent a few hours to get the same look of `ActionMode` during selecting text inside `Dialog` as in eg `Fragment`. If I select text in `Fragment`, `ActionMode`, it looks like it is from from Lollipop if in `Dialog` like on 4.3.

What is most annoying is that sometimes it is showing normal icons (grey) but sometimes they are white so you don't know what you can click. I don't have more ideas, I tried everything I found:

1. Custom style of: **actionModeStyle**
2. Specified in main style: **actionModeBackground** (doesn't work any of other options too)
3. Custom ActionMode.Callback (this one works but is showing under default ActionMode)
4. Changed theme of context passed to **AlertDialog.Builder** working but its not same as in eg fragment.

App compiled with API21, target 21, tested on SGS3. Compiling with API20 doesn't change anything, so I don't know how it is possible that `ActionMode` changed look to new design. S3 works on stock system 4.3.

**Screenshots**

In fragment
[image]

Dialog - with white icons, sometimes they are grey
[image]

Dialog - with themedContext passed to Builder
[image]

Is it possible to get the same look inside `Dialog` as is normal in `Fragment`? Or everywhere as in `Dialog`? Before one of the last updates I always had `ActionMode` as on 2nd image, but showing correctly.